# Бот модератор в тг

Tags: python, бот, telegram

Такая проблема, не могу сделать так, чтобы бот удалял сообщения только пользователей, а сообщения администраторов не трогал. Код сам работает, только не знаю, что добавить или удалить даже. Вот код:

```
import telebot
import logging

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types



logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token='cfg')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(content_types=["new_chat_members"]) #Зашел
async def on_user_joined(message: types.Message):
    await message.delete()  


@dp.message_handler(content_types=["left_chat_member"]) #Вышел
async def on_user_exit(message: types.Message):
    await message.delete()          


@dp.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
async def filter_message(message: types.Message):
    if ".ru" in message.text:
        await message.delete()
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Eсли Вы хотите отправлять ссылки со своей рекламой, обратитесь к администратору @admin")
    elif ".org" in message.text:
        await message.delete()
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Eсли Вы хотите отправлять ссылки со своей рекламой, обратитесь к администратору @admin")   
    elif ".com" in message.text:
        await message.delete()
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Eсли Вы хотите отправлять ссылки со своей рекламой, обратитесь к администратору @admin")   
    elif ".uk" in message.text:
        await message.delete()
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Eсли Вы хотите отправлять ссылки со своей рекламой, обратитесь к администратору @admin")   
    elif ".net" in message.text:
        await message.delete()  
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Eсли Вы хотите отправлять ссылки со своей рекламой, обратитесь к администратору @admin")
    elif ".info" in message.text:
        await message.delete()
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Eсли Вы хотите отправлять ссылки со своей рекламой, обратитесь к администратору @admin")
    elif "https" in message.text:
        await message.delete()
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Eсли Вы хотите отправлять ссылки со своей рекламой, обратитесь к администратору @admin") #BlackList
    elif "http" in message.text:
        await message.delete()
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Eсли Вы хотите отправлять ссылки со своей рекламой, обратитесь к администратору @admin")   
    elif "www" in message.text:
        await message.delete()
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Eсли Вы хотите отправлять ссылки со своей рекламой, обратитесь к администратору @admin")
    elif "xyz" in message.text:
        await message.delete()
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Eсли Вы хотите отправлять ссылки со своей рекламой, обратитесь к администратору @admin")           
    elif ".cite" in message.text:
        await message.delete()
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Eсли Вы хотите отправлять ссылки со своей рекламой, обратитесь к администратору @admin")   
    elif "@" in message.text:
        await message.delete()
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Eсли Вы хотите отправлять ссылки со своей рекламой, обратитесь к администратору @admin")
    elif ".to" in message.text:
        await message.delete()
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Eсли Вы хотите отправлять ссылки со своей рекламой, обратитесь к администратору @admin")                   
        



if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=False)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В общем, у меня есть несколько каналов и групп в телеграме для рекламы. То есть люди публикуют там свою рекламу. Я хочу добавить платную рекламу, которая будет содержать ссылку на сайт или телеграм канал. А без ссылки, реклама бесплатная. Ну и чтобы бот удалял ссылку и направлял на администратора, человек оплачивает рекламу и администратор публикует от своего имени рекламу и ссылку на сайт. И вот в чем проблема, бот удаляет все сообщения с ссылками, неважно, кто их отправляет обычный юзер или администратор.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй сделать так. Использовал подобный метод у себя.  Бот будет удалять сообщения ссылками и тегами (@тег) от пользователей, а от администрации нет.

PS: Так же в конфиге укажи владельца бота -- adminId = Твой Айди

```
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import AdminFilter

...


@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def delete_links(message: types.Message):
    admins_list = [admin.user.id for admin in await bot.get_chat_administrators(chat_id=message.chat.id)]
    if message.from_user.id not in admins_list:

        if '@' in message.text: #Удаление сообщений с тегами (@тег)
            await bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)

        for entity in message.entities: #Удаление сообщений с ссылками
            if entity.type in ["url", "text_link"]:
                await bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
                await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Eсли Вы хотите отправлять ссылки со своей рекламой, обратитесь к администратору @admin")
```

Comment: Удаляет тэги, при этом ничего не пишет, а вот ссылки не удаляет, даже ошибку не выдает

Comment: Для того чтобы после удаления сообщения с тегом бот писал твоё сообщение добавь `await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "текст")`

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо Вам большое)

Comment: Рад был помочь! :)